# Logging decorator fails when applied after import

Tags: python

I'm running into a strange problem that I cannot figure out.  I recently used the this [blog post](https://ankitbko.github.io/blog/2021/04/logging-in-python/) to learn how to create a logging-decorator that takes **logger** object as parameter.
When testing my decorator, it works fine when testing within ipython environment.  However, in my actual project, I saved the decorator in a file **decorator.py**.  When I import the decorator (from decorator import log_func) and apply it to a function within a module **(@log_func(some-logger-object))**, I get error.  I cant figure out why...especially considering that function hasn't actually been called yet.  Any of you folks have any ideas what's going on here?

See details below

**decorator.py**

```
from time import perf_counter
from functools import wraps
import logging

def log_func(_func=None, *, logger: logging.Logger=logging.getLogger(f"decorators:log_func")):
    """Decorator to log function entry, exit, and execution time"""
    def decorator_log_func(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper_log_func(*args, **kwargs):
            args_repr = [repr(a) for a in args]
            kwargs_repr = [f"{k}={v!r}" for k, v in kwargs.items()]
            signature = ", ".join(args_repr + kwargs_repr)
            logger.debug(f"Calling function {func.__name__} with args {signature}")
            start = perf_counter()
            result = func(*args, **kwargs)
            time_elapsed = perf_counter() - start
            logger.info(f"Exited function: {func.__name__}, Execution Time: {time_elapsed}")
            return result
        return wrapper_log_func
    if _func is None:
        return decorator_log_func
    else:
        return decorator_log_func(_func)
```

**ipython output**

```
 import logging
 log = logging.getLogger("mylogger")
 @log_func(logger=log)
 def squared(*args):
    for x in args:
        print(f"x^2 = {x**2}")

 squared(5, 6, 7)
 DEBUG:myLogger:Calling function squared with args 5, 6, 7
 x^2 = 25
 x^2 = 36
 x^2 = 49
 INFO:myLogger:Exited function: squared, Execution Time: 6.160400002386268e-05
```

Here is where failure occurs during actual code run attempt

```
python web.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "web.py", line 18, in <module>
  backend = load_backend(settings.backend)
File "/lib/backends/__init__.py", line 19, in load_backend
  globals()[name] = _backend_loaders[name].find_module(name).load_module(name)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 529, in _check_name_wrapper
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1034, in load_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 859, in load_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 274, in _load_module_shim
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 711, in _load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 855, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "/lib/backends/k8s_backend.py", line 51, in <module>
  class K8sBackend(BaseBackend):
File "/lib/backends/k8s_backend.py", line 86, in K8sBackend
  def create_task(cls, task_id: str, base: TaskBase) -> None:
File "/lib/decorators.py", line 13, in wrapper_log_func
  logger.debug(f"Calling function {func.__name__} with args {signature}")
AttributeError: 'Logger' object has no attribute '__name__'
```

In k8s_backend.py, there is a logger object defined and I imported the decorator and applied to function with the logger object passed in

**k8s_backend.py snippet**

```
from lib.decorators import log_func
import logging
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    @classmethod

@log_func(log)
def create_task(cls, task_id: str, base: TaskBase) -> None:
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is being caused by passing in an object where a function was expected.
You're passing in the logger as the function, rather than as the logger.
I think you want:

```
@log_func(logger=log)
```